# Shorten/replace user and group output of ls

Tags: string, shell, ls

Typing `ls -l` on my work laptop outputs this:

```
drwx------+  3 abcd123e  VERYLONGDOMAINNAME\Domain Users   102 May  4 09:35 Movies
drwx------+  4 abcd123e  VERYLONGDOMAINNAME\Domain Users   136 May  5 00:25 Music
drwx------+  3 abcd123e  VERYLONGDOMAINNAME\Domain Users   102 May  4 09:35 Pictures
```

Is it possible to replace the long and ugly group name (and possibly user) with an alias just for the output of `ls`, not modifying any system settings, similar to this:

```
drwx------+  3 fb  dusers   102 May  4 09:35 Movies
drwx------+  4 fb  dusers   136 May  5 00:25 Music
drwx------+  3 fb  dusers   102 May  4 09:35 Pictures
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Closest I can do without much effort is</strike>

```
alias ll="ls -l | sed -- 's/USER GROUPNAME/replacement/'"
```

**Example**

```
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x+   3 Theofanis  staff      102  4 May 13:01 Desktop
drwx------+  26 Theofanis  staff      884 20 Mar 13:59 Documents
drwx------+  22 Theofanis  staff      748  5 May 12:38 Downloads

$ alias ll="ls -l | sed -- 's/Theofanis  staff/somebody/'"

$ ll
drwxr-xr-x+   3 somebody      102  4 May 13:01 Desktop
drwx------+  26 somebody      884 20 Mar 13:59 Documents
drwx------+  22 somebody      748  5 May 12:38 Downloads
```

## Update to match new requirements

- Added `$@` so you can be able to pass parameters to *ls*.
- Added `--color=always` to constantly output with color.
- Also added an example to replace multiple combinations of user/group.

```
function ll() {
    /bin/ls -l --color=always "$@" | 
    sed -- 's/USER1 GROUPNAME1/replacement1/' | 
    sed -- 's/USER2 GROUPNAME2/replacement2/'
}
```

#### Example

```
$ ls -l
  drwxr-xr-x+   3 Theofanis  staff      102  4 May 13:01 Desktop
  drwx------+  26 Theofanis  staff      884 20 Mar 13:59 Documents
  drwx------+  22 Theofanis  staff      748  5 May 12:38 Downloads
  drwx------+  22 Theofanis  admin      748  5 May 12:38 Public

$ function ll() {
      ls -l --color=always "$@" |
      sed -- 's/Theofanis  staff/somebody/' | 
      sed -- 's/Theofanis  admin/someone/'
  }

$ ll
  drwxr-xr-x+   3 somebody      102  4 May 13:01 Desktop
  drwx------+  26 somebody      884 20 Mar 13:59 Documents
  drwx------+  22 somebody      748  5 May 12:38 Downloads
  drwx------+  22 someone      748  5 May 12:38 Public

$ ll -F # appends '/' on directories
  drwxr-xr-x+   3 somebody      102  4 May 13:01 Desktop/
  drwx------+  26 somebody      884 20 Mar 13:59 Documents/
  drwx------+  22 somebody      748  5 May 12:38 Downloads/
  drwx------+  22 someone      748  5 May 12:38 Public/
```

Comment: Thanks. This definitely works in terms of replacing the text, but there are at least two minor issues: 1. `sed` removes color, unless `--color=always` is specified for `ls`. 2. It is not possible to use arguments like `ll -a`, as it would be passed to `sed` instead of `ls`.

Comment: @Theofanis, change that to `"$@"` to support arguments with spaces etc.

Comment: @alexis I believe these arguments should be wrapped in quotes when calling *ll* but anyway

Comment: Try it! The quotes will get lost and you'll have a problem unless your function reinserts them. It's how bash parsing works.

Comment: @friederbluemle does this matches your needs?

Comment: @Theofanis Yes much better! Thanks. You can also avoid two separate invocations to `sed` like so: `sed -- 's/old1/new1/;s/old2/new2/'`